# Recyclerview notifyitemRangeChanged - как обновить позиции элементов?

Tags: java, android, list, recyclerview, position

Есть recyclerview, в него из сети загружаются данные. При нажатии на определенные элементы в recyclerview должны добавляться новые или удаляться старые строки, в коде добавление выглядит так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectToInsert.size(); i++) {
                objects.add(i + position + 1, objectToInsert.get(i));
                notifyItemInserted(i + position + 1);
            }
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position + 1, objects.size());
```

Есть массив данных для добавления objectToInsert, прохожусь по каждому элементу добавляя его в основной массив данных для recycler view.

Позиция элемента получается следующим образом: в `onBindViewHolder` я добавляю к вьюшке teg, например, `holder.objectIcon.setTag(position);` и в нужном мне месте я его беру:

```
 try {
        position = (Integer) view.getTag();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("NANADEVPOS", e.toString());
        return;
    }
```

Удаление строк делается аналогично:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectToRemove.size(); i++) {
            objects.remove(position + 1);
            notifyItemRemoved(position + 1);
        }

        notifyItemRangeChanged(position + 1, objects.size());
```

И иногда вылетает: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 5`.

Если в коде заменить метод `notifyItemRangeChanged` на `notifyDataSetChanged` эксепшены не вылетают и приложение работает стабильно, но пропадает анимация добавления и удаления элементов.

**В связи с этим вопрос:** как правильно добавлять/удалять в recyclerview массив элементов? Или как сохранить анимацию добавления/удаления при использовании `notifyDataSetChanged`

Для наглядности прикреплю скриншот списка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иерархический список, в котором при нажатии на элементы они сворачиваются или разворачиваются.

Comment: Какого поведения Вы ждали, прибавляя к position + 1?

Comment: @Asgard Я добавляю массив элементов после определенной позиции. В результате получается подобие иерархического списка. Но возможно я не прав, объясните почему не правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось достаточно простым, в качестве позиции нужно брать не позицию по тегу, а позицию адаптера с помощью метода `getAdapterPosition()`:

`int position = holder.getAdapterPosition()`. Весь основной алгоритм отображения/скрытия, описанный выше, - правильный.